# Retrieve price data from PancakeSwap [BSC]

Tags: exchange-api, decentralized-exchange, bsc

1. Does PancakeSwap use the same constant product formula as Uniswap (x * y = k)? Because then I should be able to calculate a token pair exchange rate by just dividing the amount of token1 reserves by the amount of token2 reserves.
2. Is there an API that could deliver me the wanted token pair exchange rates?
3. Is there any other function in their contract to fetch price data from?

Comment: I am voting to close this question because this question is not about Ethereum blockchain, but it is about Binance Smart Chain and belongs to a different forum.

Comment: @Mikko Ohtamaa the Binance Smart Chain runs on the EVM like Ethereum...

Comment: I would agree with OP. Almost all questions relating to Ethereum apply to BSC, It makes no sense to have a separate stackexchange for BSC.

Answer (score 2):

Pancake Swap uses the same formula as Uniswap, but they have a 0.2% fee instead of 0.3% fee, which affects the calculation.

Comment: I can easily find Uniswap router address online, but I am not able to find PancakeSwap router address online, I want to use the router to swap a token from my ERC20 contract.

Comment: https://bscscan.com/address/0x05ff2b0db69458a0750badebc4f9e13add608c7f

Comment: Please consider that they have recently migrated to V2 and therefore also created a new router and factory contract! -> New router contract: 0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E
-> New Factory contract: 0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73